# How to delete a node from a linked list using an integer variable in c++

Tags: visual-c++, linked-list, int, delete-operator

In my project I am creating a linked list. Currently I am making a function that deletes a node based on its position by the number that the user puts in. The problem I am having with this function is that one of my variables pnode keeps getting listed as an uninitialized local variable every time I try to run the program. Here is what the code looks like

```
Class list{
  private:
   struct nodelist{
     int hold;
     nodelist *next

   }; 
   nodelist *head
  public:
     void deleteitem(int n){
         nodelist *nodepr
         nodelist *pnode
         if(!head){
           return;
         }
        if(n==0){
           nodepr=head->next;
           delete head;
           head=nodepr;
        }
        else{
           nodepr=head;
           int index=1;
           while(nodepr!=NULL && index!=n){
                pnode=nodepr;
                nodepr=nodepr->next;
                index++;




          }
          if(index==n){
             pnode->next=nodepr->next;
             delete nodepr;


          }






      }


}
```

Note that their are other functions to this class.

Comment: Where do you define the variable `num`? In the line `if(num==0)` is that suppose to read `if(n==0)`?

Comment: It was supposed to be the n variable sorry

Comment: @user2340686 For `num=1`, the code exhibits undefined behavior because `pnode` is not initialized. Can you show how list is populated ?

Comment: There are unbalanced `{ }`. Fix you code that it passes the compiler. Reformat would also help.

Comment: Indent properly, remove extra blank lines, and you are missing `;` -> Post code that compiles and is *readable*.

Comment: @user2340686 Since you are not "fixing" your code shown... "The problem I am having with this function is that one of my variables pnode keeps getting listed as an unintailized local variable every time I try to run the program" <-- look at the code. It is easy to see that you *don't* initialize `pnode`. Try debugging.